# What is meaning of 'had done well' in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

I want to know the meaning of  the expression 'had done well'. I read it in the book Fantastic Mr. Fox by Roald Dahl.

'THE OWNERS OF THESE FARMS HAD DONE WELL. THEY WERE RICH MEN. THEY ARE ALSO NASTY MEN.'

At first, i think this is same with 'good job'. But in that book, the men who 'had done well' is very nasty and mean. Is it sarcastic expression?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its an abbreviation of the idiom ** DONE WELL FOR THEMSELVES**
I am sure the author is alluding to this idiom as he then goes on to tell us

> THEY WERE RICH MEN
>
> **do well for (oneself)** [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+well+for+themselves)
>
> To find success financially and/or in one's career.
>
> I can see from the sports car she's driving that Mary is doing well for herself these days.